# Создание классов

Tags: php, ооп

Правильно ли создавать 2 класса в одном файле php?.

Comment: Смотря какие классы. Если классы как-то логически связаны, то почему нет?

Comment: В 98% случаев вам скажут, что расположение в одном файле - bad practice..... Однако всё зависит, знаете ли

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, не правильно, но PHP позволяет это сделать, как и размещение классов в разных пространствах имён внутри одного файла.

Считайте, что это Bad Practice.

Comment: А если это internal class? как в java вложенные (nested и inner)? почему нет?

Comment: Читайте PSR-1: Namespaces and classes MUST follow an “autoloading” PSR: [PSR-0, PSR-4].

This means each class is in a file by itself, and is in a namespace of at least one level: a top-level vendor name.

Поэтому если вы хотите писать "хороший код", то данное поведение не рекомендовано.

Comment: А зачем мне автолоад для inner класса?) Он создается за счет родителя

Comment: PSR-1 вообще не про autoload, он про базовые вещи.

Comment: Я знаю что такое PSR, спасибо)  Однако это никак не отменяет тот факт, что inner классы, которые используются в outer ни коим образом не попадут и не попадают в autoload и если относятся только к ним - могут быть расположены внутри

Comment: А где я говорил, что они не могут? Вопрос по моему был про "правильно" и "неправильно". У Java свои понятия правильности, у PHP свои.

Comment: Так всё же, я не понял, почему это неправильно?)

Answer (score 1):

Нет, неправильно, потому что автолоад.

Ну то есть теоретически это возможно, но на практике автолоад будет искать класс для загрузки в файле, совпадающем с именем класса.

Comment: Можно использовать второй класс, если он не нужен в autoload, например в том случае, когда он используется только в первом классе. Но на практике кроме раздувания файла это ничего не даёт.